# Attempting to build xerces c++ parser. Netbeans & command line build error undefined reference to `xercesc_3_2...'

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans, makefile

Im attempting to Xerces c++ parser library in a NetBeans project built on Linux RedHat.

**I followed the build guide (https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/build-3.html#UNIX)**

1) downloaded tar.gz "xerces-c-3.2.2.tar.gz"

2) using " tar xvzf" extracted to tar user my /home/myuser/projects as  xerces-c-3.2.2

3) Navigated to /home/myuser/projects/ xerces-c-3.2.2 & issued at the command line on linux

**./configure --disable-shared --disable-static**

There was alot of output but no errors, next:

4) I ran **"make"** in the same directory. A lot of .o & .lo files were created...

output was like this:

```
 CXX      src/SEnumVal/SEnumVal.o
  CXXLD    SEnumVal
  CXX      src/StdInParse/StdInParse.o
  CXX      src/StdInParse/StdInParseHandlers.o
  CXXLD    StdInParse
  CXX      src/XInclude/XInclude.o
  CXXLD    XInclude

    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/myUser/projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/samples'
    make[2]: Entering directory `/home/myUser/projects/xerces-c-3.2.2'
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/myUser/projects/xerces-c-3.2.2'
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/myUser/projects/xerces-c-3.2.2'
```

There were no errors, next:

5) cd /src & ls -a shows .libs directory are built.

cd into /home/myUser/projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/.libs shows:

```
libxerces-c.a  libxerces-c.la  libxerces-c.lai
```

**6) Attempting  to run sample code, based on the programming guide (http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/program-3.html):**

```
#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>
// Other include files, declarations, and non-Xerces-C++ initializations.

using namespace xercesc;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try {
    XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
  }
  catch (const XMLException& toCatch) {
    // Do your failure processing here
    return 1;
  }

  // Do your actual work with Xerces-C++ here.

  XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();

  // Other terminations and cleanup.
  return 0;
}
```

**Before pressed project properties, c++ compiler, Include directories & added the following paths**

1)../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc

2)../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src

3)../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/.libs

**And included paths to headers:**

1) ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp

2) ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/XMLUni.hpp

3) ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/XMLException.hpp

**I also went to project properties, Linker and added "Additional Library Directories" & "Runtime Search Directories"**

1)../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc

2)../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src

3)../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/.libs

**Finally I pressed clean & build in Netbeans, reported compiler commands & errors:**

```
cd '/home/myUser/NetBeansProjects/SOFF_test'
/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile CONF=Debug clean
"/usr/bin/gmake" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .clean-conf
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/home/myUser/NetBeansProjects/SOFF_test'
rm -f -r build/Debug
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/home/myUser/NetBeansProjects/SOFF_test'

CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 209ms)

cd '/home/myUser/NetBeansProjects/SOFF_test'
/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/usr/bin/gmake" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/home/myUser/NetBeansProjects/SOFF_test'
"/usr/bin/gmake"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/soff_test
gmake[2]: Entering directory `/home/myUser/NetBeansProjects/SOFF_test'
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newmain.o.d"

g++    -c -g -I../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc -I../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src -include ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp -include ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/XMLUni.hpp -include ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/XMLException.hpp -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newmain.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newmain.o newmain.cpp

mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux

g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/soff_test build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newmain.o -L../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/ -L../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/ -L../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/.libs -Wl,-rpath,'../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/' -Wl,-rpath,'../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newmain.o: 

In function `main':
/home/myUser/NetBeansProjects/SOFF_test/newmain.cpp:26: undefined reference to `xercesc_3_2::XMLUni::fgXercescDefaultLocale'

/home/myUser/NetBeansProjects/SOFF_test/newmain.cpp:26: undefined reference to `xercesc_3_2::XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize(char const*, char const*, xercesc_3_2::PanicHandler*, xercesc_3_2::MemoryManager*)'

/home/myUser/NetBeansProjects/SOFF_test/newmain.cpp:36: undefined reference to `xercesc_3_2::XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate()'

build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newmain.o:(.gcc_except_table+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for xercesc_3_2::XMLException'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/soff_test] Error 1
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/home/myUser/NetBeansProjects/SOFF_test'
gmake[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/home/myUser/NetBeansProjects/SOFF_test'
gmake: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 456ms)
```

**If you refer to g++ compile command:**

```
  g++    -c -g -I../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc -I../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src -include ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp -include ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/XMLUni.hpp -include ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/XMLException.hpp -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newmain.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newmain.o newmain.cpp


    g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/soff_test build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newmain.o -L../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/ -L../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/ -L../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/.libs -Wl,-rpath,'../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/' -Wl,-rpath,'../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/'
    build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newmain.o:
```

**You can see the headers for the code sample are included:**

```
-include ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp -include ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/XMLUni.hpp -include ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/XMLException.hpp
```

**Also the Linker has been provided the .libs & src (might not be required) folders**

```
-L../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/ -L../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/ -L../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/.libs
```

NetBeans is able to see the `#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>`& I can even click into the xerces PlatformUtils.hpp & see the function implementations via the IDE.

**1) Why is NetBeans not able to compile & find the Xerces libraries even though IDE can resolve the headers?**

**2) Ultimately, how can I fix this issue? (Are my includes correct?)**

**Updates:**

Original errors "undefined references" that are stated above are resolved based  on recommendations from user "jww" see comments.

1) I ch**anged the #include  to #include "xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp"
2) Also added libxerces-c.a via Project Properties, then Linker, Libraries menu.**

**These are the updated build commands that NetBeans generates:**

```
  g++    -c -g -I../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc -I../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src -I../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/.libs -include ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp -include ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/XMLUni.hpp -include ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/XMLException.hpp -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newmain.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newmain.o newmain.cpp
    mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux


    g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/soff_test build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newmain.o -L../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/ -L../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/ -L../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/.libs -Wl,-rpath,'../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/.libs' -Wl,-rpath,'../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src' -Wl,-rpath,'../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc' -lxerces-c
```

**You can see that -lxerces-c flag was addeded.**

Now I naturally have new errors , that are not related to the sample code, but deep in xerces library code, they again on the "undefined references" nature.

```
See below:

/home/anaim/projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/NetAccessors/Curl/CurlNetAccessor.cpp:70: undefined reference to `curl_global_init'

/home/anaim/projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/NetAccessors/Curl/CurlNetAccessor.cpp:70: undefined reference to `curl_global_init'

../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/.libs/libxerces-c.a(CurlNetAccessor.o): In function `xercesc_3_2::CurlNetAccessor::cleanupCurl()':
/home/anaim/projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/NetAccessors/Curl/CurlNetAccessor.cpp:78: undefined reference to `curl_global_cleanup'

../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/.libs/libxerces-c.a(CurlURLInputStream.o): In function `xercesc_3_2::CurlURLInputStream::readMore(int*)':
/home/anaim/projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/NetAccessors/Curl/CurlURLInputStream.cpp:269: undefined reference to `curl_multi_perform'

Etc, etc...
```

I also resolved above error and more by adding -lcurl & -lpthread

This is the latest compile commnads (again its NetBeans generated)

```
g++    -c -g -I../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc -I../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src -include ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp -include ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/XMLUni.hpp -include ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/XMLException.hpp -include ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/NetAccessors/Curl/CurlNetAccessor.hpp -include ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/NetAccessors/Curl/CurlURLInputStream.hpp -include ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/Transcoders/ICU/ICUTransService.hpp -include ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/xinclude/XIncludeDOMDocumentProcessor.hpp -include ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/xinclude/XIncludeLocation.hpp -include ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/xinclude/XIncludeUtils.hpp -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newmain.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newmain.o newmain.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux


g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/soff_test build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newmain.o -L../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/ -L../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/ -L../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/.libs -Wl,-rpath,'../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src' -Wl,-rpath,'../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc' -Wl,-rpath,'../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/.libs' -lxerces-c -lcurl -lpthread
```

**New Errors:**

Again the "undefined references":

../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/.libs/libxerces-c.a(ICUTransService.o): In function `xercesc_3_2::ICUTransService::upperCase(unsigned short*)':
/home/anaim/projects/xerces-c-
3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/Transcoders/ICU/ICUTransService.cpp:358: undefined reference to`u_toupper_50'

Etc...

1) So do I have to repeat the same steps & add headers to the path until these are resolved?

This seems like a NetBeans issue?

If the developer provides the write path to library(in this case xerces) and NetBeans is able to see the library (which it does), why cant NetBeans generate the right compiler/linker commands, isnt that the whole point of a C/C++ IDE?

MY LATEST ATTEMPT:

I have moved on to using a custom Makefile that is not NetBeans dependent.

**Here is Makefile:**

```
   # vars c++
CXX := g++
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11 -Wall -g 

#collect  all c++ files $(wildcard *.cpp)
SOURCES_CC = newmain.cpp 

#vars c
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -std=c99 -Wall -g

#collect all c files
SOURCES_C := $(wildcard *.c) 

#objects 
OBJECTS_DIR := build

#construct objects from .c and .cpp to .o
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES_C:%.c=%.o) $(SOURCES_CC:%.cpp=%.o)

#final executable in dist 
DIST_DIR := dist
PROGRAM  := $(DIST_DIR)/main

#required libraries 
LDFLAGS = -L../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/ -lxerces-c

debug := CFLAGS

.PHONY: all
all debug: $(PROGRAM)

$(PROGRAM): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean
    clean:
    rm -f $(PROGRAM) $(OBJECTS)
```

**Here is the latest error:**

```
cd '/home/myuser/NetBeansProjects/SOFF_test'
/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile CONF=Debug
gmake: *** No rule to make target `-I../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc', needed by `dist/main'.  Stop.
```

I was able to build xerces using this command line:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g -L../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/ -o main newmain.cpp -lxerces-c
```

**Here is my ONLY  question! How can alter this custom Makefile to build the sample xerces example with also my own source files (.c and .cpp)

Thanks a million!

Comment: If you did not perform `sudo make install` into a system directory, then the include `#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>` is likely incorrect. Use double quotes, and not lt and gt brackets. I think there's a compiler option that tells the compiler to treat non-system-directories as if they were system directories, but I don't recall what it is.

Comment: Put another way, use `-I $HOME/projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/` compiler option, and use `#include "xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp"`.

Comment: For the linker problem, you never specify the library with `-l` (lowercase elle). You only specify the path to the library with `-L`. You need to add the actual library to `LDFLAGS` with  `-lxerces` or `-l:libxerces-c.a` or similar.

Comment: @jww, firstly thank you very much. I updated to #include "xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp"  & also via Properties, Linker menu  pointed to libxerces-c.a & it was recognized. I had those original errors resolved , however I have new errors that are  again undefined  references but NOT in the sample code they originate from  deep in the xerecs library.  I will update my post with the details.

Comment: In your original configure call you use both "disable shared libraries" and "disable static libraries", but you later want to use a static library. Are you sure this is the right option? While we're at it, I would also suggest that you switch to building with CMake, which for a subtree-static build as the one you are attempting, would make things way easier.

Comment: @JavierMartín, Im will run the ./configure instead of ./configure --disable-shared --disable-static. So how do I proceed with a custom make file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comments, here is a bare-bones makefile .. hope this helps :)

```
CC = gcc
CXX = g++
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -Wall
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall

PROGRAM  = dist/main

SOURCES_C = $(wildcard *.c) 
SOURCES_CC = newmain.cpp 

OBJS = $(SOURCES_C:%.c=%.o) $(SOURCES_CC:%.cpp=%.o)

LIBS = -L../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/ -lxerces-c

all: $(PROGRAM)

clean:
    rm -f $(PROGRAM) $(OBJS) 

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<

%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $<

$(PROGRAM): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: all clean
```

Answer (score 0):

In your custom makefile, this line

```
$(PROGRAM): $(INCLUDES) $(OBJECTS)
```

is incorrect. You told make that your program depends on the object files **and the preprocessor options that tell the compiler where the include files are located**. `-I../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc` is not a file on which your executable depends.

Remove `$(INCLUDES)` from that line and use it as a preprocessor option:

```
CPPFLAGS := $(INCLUDES)

$(PROGRAM): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

You probably need a `-L../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/` in your `LDFLAGS`.

Note: you are using the `SOURCES_CC` variable, but aren't defining it anywhere.

Comment: I was able to build the project using command line `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g -L../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/ -o main newmain.cpp -lxerces-c` how can i alter my Makefile to do this.

Answer (score 0):

A well-meaning moderator 'Cody' deleted this (below) answer without explanation, even though it's part of the right answer. In a nutshell, dude is asking about his/her custom makefile, not something generated by Netbeans.

I also noticed a reply from a person with regards to removing the '.d' file from the object's build dependencies .. often (but not always) these are these are updated after the compile, but they also need to be built before the initial compile can happen. Simply removing them from the objects dependencies may mean that if anything changes in the headers the affected objects may not be rebuilt even though they depend on those headers. This is sort of a chicken-egg paradox, and the way around it is to build a special target like 'depend' .. that would be 'make depend'. I didn't see this target in the Makefile snippet, but maybe I missed it? The other, less common approach is to craft a macro like 'NODEPS' that adds some conditionality in the makefile to avoid/skip adding the '.d' files as dependencies. So you'd do 'make NODEPS=1' on your initial build and then subsequent to that the 'chicken' would be present for subsequent 'make ' builds.

Here is his/her last question: Here is my only question! How can alter this custom Makefile to build the sample : xerces example with also my own source files (.c and .cpp)?

If you do an 'ls ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc' from within /home/myuser/NetBeansProjects/SOFF_test directory .. does it find that directory, in other words, is that relative path valid from where you are running the compiler? If not then you'll need to change it - it may be as simple as adding an extra ../ in there, such as -

INCLUDES := -I../../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc -I../../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src -include ../../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp -include ../../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/XMLUni.hpp -include ../../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/util/XMLException.hpp -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newmain.o.d"

Comment: @Adrew Atrens, yes the ls ../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc command executed correctly from /home/myuser/NetBeansProjects/SOFF_test.

Comment: curious where 'dist/main' is in relation .. can re-run make as 'make -w' to see what directory you are really in when you hit this error?

Comment: when I ran "make -w'  I  got `serverxyz{myuser}% make -w
make: Entering directory `/home/myuser/NetBeansProjects/SOFF_test
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make: Leaving directory `/home/myuser/NetBeansProjects/SOFF_test`

Comment: @Adrew Atrens, I have uploaded a new simplified Makefile that I would like to use instead of this command at the command line `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g -L../../projects/xerces-c-3.2.2/src/xercesc/ -o main newmain.cpp -lxerces-c` what are your  thoughts. I was able to get xerces to compile and run uinsg the that g++ compiler command however I want to use a proper Makefile.